# add event log to registry

Tags: c#, registry, event-log

I'm attempting to access a 'ForwardedEvents' events log on a server using

```
el = new EventLog("ForwardedEvents", serverName);
```

this isn't working.

I believe it's not working because the log isn't contained in the registry where Eventlog would expect to find it (HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet/Services/Eventlog/.. ).

How would add the log to registry so it is found, or is there another method to access a log that's not specified in that location?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remedied the issue by creating a new registry entry for the Log at:
 (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\LOGNAME).

Did this by.. ( on windows server 2008 R2 ) ..

1) Right Click on parent folder (eventlog) -> New -> Key

2) Name the key like the evtx file found at (C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\LOGNAME)

3) In the right pane of the registry explorer, right click -> new -> Expandable String Value

4) Name the newly created REG_EXPAND_SZ "File"

5) Right click on the Name "File"

6) Modify

7)In the "Value Data" box, add path to evtx file like

( %SystemRoot%\System32\winevt\Logs\ForwardedEvents.evtx )

Comment: This answer helped me, thanks! It seems to work without adding the Expandable String Value or editing the File value. I added [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803351/how-do-i-read-from-an-arbitrary-evxt-file-using-system-diagnostics-eventlog) which details how I solved it.

Comment: Creating the key at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application was enough for me too, but I needed to give permission in this new key to the user running the application(NETWORK SERVICE  in this case).

Answer (score 5):

This is close to the other registry solution offered here, but this is how I did it on Windows 7, and will write to the Application log, not the Forwarded Events log:

- Windows logo > type `regedit` in the search and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Expand `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog`
- Find the `Application` key and create a new key for your application:  `MyApp`
- In `MyApp`, right-click the right side window in the blank area and select **New > Expandable String Value**.  This will create a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` entry.  Give it the name `EventMessageFile`.
- Double-click the new entry to set a value.  For the value, enter:
  `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\EventLogMessages.dll`
  Select **OK**.
- Leave the `(Default)` string value alone with its `(value not set)` value.
- Repeat two more times by replacing `CurrentControlSet` with `ControlSet001` and `ControlSet002`.

And if you need to then move your application to another computer, you can right-click the key and select `Export`.  You save the file as a `.reg` file, and then copy it to the next computer.  There, you double-click to run it (while logged in as an Administrator).  In this way, you don't have to manually re-create it, and for other apps, you can actually edit the `.reg` file in Notepad and simply change the name of the app, save it (be sure to change the format to "All Files", so it retains the `.reg` on the end, and not save it as a `.txt` file), and then you can double-click it to run and insert the new app's EventLog key.

Answer (score 3):

If you still want to do this the programmatic way as opposed to manually creating the log via the registry, there is a way. You need to check and see if the `EventSource` exists first, and if it doesn't you need to create it. This has to happen all before you try to create an `EventLog` instance with that source. Just note the latency between creation and use, so make sure to handle this (see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2awhba7a(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2awhba7a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information).

```
// Create the source, if it does not already exist. 
if(!EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
{
    //An event log source should not be created and immediately used. 
    //There is a latency time to enable the source, it should be created 
    //prior to executing the application that uses the source. 
    //Execute this sample a second time to use the new source.
    EventLog.CreateEventSource("MySource", "MyNewLog");
    Console.WriteLine("CreatedEventSource");
    Console.WriteLine("Exiting, execute the application a second time to use the source.");
    // The source is created.  Exit the application to allow it to be registered. 
    return;
}

// Create an EventLog instance and assign its source.
EventLog myLog = new EventLog();
myLog.Source = "MySource";

// Write an informational entry to the event log.    
myLog.WriteEntry("Writing to event log.");
```

Comment: One minor problem with your code is that if you using OS >= Vista, unless you have admin privileges then SourceExists will fail with a SecurityException (as I just found out when porting code from XP to W7).  In which case you either need to give the app admin privileges or create the key yourself (either manually, or during a .msi install for example)

Comment: If you run the app as an Administrator you shouldn't have any problems.  If the UAC bit is still pitching a fit, you can run a command prompt as an Administrator, then run the app that contains this code from there by navigating with DOS to the app's path (i.e. if your app was called "myapp.exe" and was in C:\Temp, then: `C:>cd C:\Temp` then `C:\Temp>myapp.exe`).