# How do I read from an arbitrary evxt file using System.Diagnostics.EventLog?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, event-log

How can I use [`EventLog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.EventLog%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to read from an arbitrary `evtx` file?

[`EventLogQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is able to open `evtx` files, but it is not available in .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the log file is `LogA.evtx`.

Copy `LogA.evtx` to `C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs`.

Add a new registry key to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog
```

called `LogA`. E.g. in PowerShell:

```
Set-Location HKLM:

New-Item .\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog -Name LogA
```

Open Event Viewer to verify that *LogA* shows up under *Applications and Services Logs*.

You can now open `LogA` using `EventLog`:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace EventLogTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var log = new EventLog("LogA");

            Console.WriteLine(log.Entries.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

You can delete `LogA` via PowerShell:

```
[System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::Delete("LogA")
```